# FFMPEG: Can i set an audio to be played at night only?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, youtube, stream

This is my working command:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://stream1video -i rtsp://stream2audio -re -stream_loop -1 -i 1.aac -re -stream_loop -1 -i 2.aac -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a][3:a]amix=inputs=3[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/`

Now, can i somehow set playing the audio streams only at the night? e.g. between 22:00-06:00 each day? And the rest of the day would be just the silence :)

edit: i'm using linux.

Comment: Use a cronjob (or similar as your OS is unknown) to execute the above command at your desired times.

Answer (score 0):

Use un cron job (linux/mac) or planified task on windows

Comment: That could work but my cameras doesn't like restarting ffmpeg scripts, usually they hangs.

Comment: From FFMPEG, It would not be possible. FFMPEG doesn't embed a cron like system but perhaps with command script as "pause" ? I work with cron, I can't explain more...